# Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled, need to use CUDA on my local PC

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use my video card to analise some ML task.

I'm using this code:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("cointegrated/rubert-tiny2")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("cointegrated/rubert-tiny2")
model.cuda()  # uncomment it if you have a GPU

def embed_bert_cls(text, model, tokenizer):
    t = tokenizer(text, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')
    with torch.no_grad():
        model_output = model(**{k: v.to(model.device) for k, v in t.items()})
    embeddings = model_output.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]
    embeddings = torch.nn.functional.normalize(embeddings)
    return embeddings[0].cpu().numpy()
```

and get this error:

`AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled`

I check my system and drivers and get this:

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

`false`

so i look in to version of torch:

```
torch.__version__
```

`2.0.1+cpu`

```
nvcc --version
```

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Apr__3_17:36:15_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.105
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32688072_0
```

```
nvidia-smi
```

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 531.68                 Driver Version: 531.68       CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I wipe all my libs on pip and get fresh install from:

```
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/torch_stable.html
```

but still get `2.0.1+cpu` version fo torch and cuda `not available`.

My OS is Windows 10 x64.
I prefer not to use `conda`, only `pip`. I want to use my video card for ML analyse.

Comment: You have installed a build of PyTorch without GPU support . You must find a GPU enabled build and then install its prerequisites to get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong link in the install, you can open it in the browser to check if it is accesible, the [install](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) guide gives you the correct install command (except with `pip`) for `3.8-3.11`.

```
[Stable]  https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
[Nightly] https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu121  (with --pre)
```

If you are going to use `pip` you should be using `virtualenv` too if you aren't already using it.

Comment: sure, my mistake was in thought what cu121 belong "stable" version, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did indeed the same mistake and of course, when installing the right version, everything goes faster and properly ...

```
pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu121
```